# elastic search for mark character

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two fields in Vietnamese: "**mắt biếc**" and "**mật mã**" in an index call books.

In books index, i use accifolding to transform from "**mắt biếc**" to "**mat biec**" and "**mật mã**" to "**mat ma**".

In two fields above, i need to query for a term : "**mắt**". But the score of two field is equal and what i want is "**mắt biếc**" have score greater than "**mật mã**".

So, how can i do that in elastic search.

Comment: Can you please share your mappings?

Comment: Yeah, here is my mapping  mappings: {
          properties: {
            title: {
              type: "text",
              analyzer: "product_analyzer"
            },
            price: {
              type: "keyword",
              index: false
            },
            author: {
              type: "keyword",
              index: false
            },
            publisher: {
              type: "keyword",
              index: false
            }
          }

Comment: @AssaelAzran the "mắt biếc" and "mật mã" is term for "title" field

Comment: See my answer. let me know if something is not clear

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Function Score Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)

Try this (base on version 7.x):

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "title": "mật"
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "title.keyword": {
                 "value": "mắt biếc"
              }
            }
          },
          "weight": 30
        }
      ],
      "max_boost": 30,
      "score_mode": "max",
      "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

**Mappings example**

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "product_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "product_analyzer",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "price": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "author": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "publisher": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You have to update your mappings in order to use `title.keyword`

**Update Query**

```
POST my_index/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "text",
      "analyzer": "product_analyzer",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then

**Update all documents**

```
  POST my_index/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
```

Hope this helps